# odeint is giving incredibly wrong results when numerically integrating hamilton's equations of motion

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I'm at my wits end with this.  I am trying to numerically integrate these four equations produced from

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import math
# Parameters describing the system
L = 15
l1 = 5
l2 = 10
g = 9.8
m = 0.5
k1 = 3
k2 = 5
# Assign initial conditions to the motion.
x0 = 0.
xDot0 = 0.
theta0 = 0.
thetaDot0 = 0.
u0 = [x0, xDot0, theta0, thetaDot0]  # initial conditions for all 4 variables
# This function gives the time derivative of each of the 4 variables. These correspond to the
# four Hamilton equations of motion (1st-order differential equations)
def dudt(u, t):
    r = [0., 0., 0., 0.]
    s = np.sqrt(-2.0*L*(l1 + u[0])*np.cos(u[2]) + L**2 +(l1 + u[0])**2)
    a = l1 + u[0]
    p_theta = u[3]*m*pow(a, 2)

    r[0] = u[1] # enter the time derivative of y
    r[1] = (2.0/m)*pow(a, -3)*pow(p_theta, 2) - k1*u[0] - k2*((L*math.cos(u[2]) - l1 - u[0])*(1 - l2/s)) - m*g*math.sin(u[2])  # enter the time derivative of py
    r[2] = u[3] # enter the time derivative of theta
    r[3] =  -(k2*(L*(a)*math.sin(u[0]))*(1-l2/s)) -m*g*math.cos(u[2])   # enter the time derivative of ptheta
    return r

# Use the scipy odeint routine to carry out the numerical integration of the system
# of equations.
t0 = 0                   # start time
t1 = 20              # end time
# Choose a set of time values at which to evaluate the solution y(t)
t = np.linspace(t0,t1,1000)
# Call the routing from scipy that does the integration
u = odeint(dudt, u0, t)
font = {'size'   : 18}
plt.rc('font', **font)
# Use pyplot from matplotlib to plot the motion y(t)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
plt.xlim(t0, t1)
ax.set_xlabel('t (s)')
ax.set_ylabel('x (m)')
ax.plot(t,u[...,0])
plt.show()
# Plot the motion theta(t)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
plt.xlim(t0, t1)
ax.set_xlabel('t (s)')
ax.set_ylabel('theta (degrees)')
ax.plot(t,u[...,2]*180./math.pi)
plt.show()
```

And I get the following junk plots:

[Plot of x vs. time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66s7M.png)

[Plot of angle vs. time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uB6um.png)

Along with the following error:

`/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/odepack.py:247: ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
  warnings.warn(warning_msg, ODEintWarning)`

I'm not sure how to proceed from here, the warning frankly isn't very helpful for me.

Comment: It looks like the solution is blowing up at about t=1.  Double check your implementation of the differential equations.  Are you sure there are no sign errors, missing terms, incorrect variables, etc?

Comment: I have done as you said, reimplementing the differential equations as the following:

`r[1] = (2.0*a*u[3]) - k1*u[0] - k2*x2*(a - L*math.cos(u[2]))/s - m*g*math.sin(u[2])`

`r[3] =  -(k2*x2*(L*(a)*math.sin(u[2]))/s) -m*g*math.cos(u[2]) `

Including before these in the function definition:

`s = np.sqrt(-2.0*L*(l1 + u[0])*np.cos(u[2]) + L**2 +(l1 + u[0])**2)`

And now it seems to be plotting the appropriate motions!